# C++/Tk how to exequte general tcl code?

Tags: c++, user-interface, tcl, execution, tk-toolkit

So we have code like:

```
#include "cpptk.h"
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace Tk;

void hello() {
     puts("Hello C++/Tk!");
}

int main(int, char *argv[])
{
    static char* str = "button .a -text "Say Hello ppure TCL"\n"
                   "pack .a\n";
     init(argv[0]);

     button(".b") -text("Say Hello") -command(hello);
     pack(".b") -padx(20) -pady(6);

     runEventLoop();
}
```

imagine `str` is complex tcl code. We want to feed it to C++/Tk as a string. Also we want to have it exequted in the same TCL vm our general C++/Tk programm with gui we created in C++/Tk code runs. So the result of this code would be 2 buttons inside a window.
How to do such thing?

How to do such thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you got access to the `Tcl_Interp*` handle used inside C++/Tk? If so (and assuming here you've got it in a variable called `interp`) use:

```
int resultCode = Tcl_Eval(interp, str);
```

Next, check the `resultCode` to see if it is `TCL_OK` or `TCL_ERROR` (other values are possible, but uncommon in normal scripts). That tells you the interpretation of the “result”, which you get like this:

```
const char *result = Tcl_GetString(Tcl_GetObjResult(interp));
```

If the result code says its an error, `result` is now an error message. If it was ok, the `result` is the output of the script (NB: not what was written to standard out though). It's up to you what to do with that.

---

[EDIT]: I looked this up in more detail. It's nastier than it appears, because C++/Tk hides away Tcl quite deep inside itself. In so far as I can see, you do this (untested!):

```c++
#include "cpptk.h" // might need "base/cpptkbase.h" instead
#include <string>

// This next part is in a function or method...
std::string script("the script to evaluate goes here");
std::string result = Tk::details::Expr(script,true);
```

Comment: If you haven't got the Tcl_Interp, you'll have to make one with `Tcl_CreateInterp()`. That's more complex though, and you won't be able to interact with the GUI from it.